# How to successfully complete an in app purchase using flutter on android?

Tags: android, flutter, google-play, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

### What I want

I want to integrate Google Play in app purchases into my flutter app, the product I want to sell is a consumable. Right now I am using the `in_app_purchase: (0.3.4+16)` package.

### What I did

- Create the product in the google play developer console
- Set up the project according to the documentation of the in_app_purchase package
- Implemented some logic to buy a consumable item (see below)
- Built an alpha release and uploaded it to the alpha test track in order to test it
- Created a new google account on my developer phone, registered it as tester and downloaded the alpha version
- Purchased with a "test card, always approves"
- Purchased with my PayPal account

### Expected and actual result

I expect the payment to work and all api calls to return ok.

When I initiate a purchase on my phone the purchase flow starts and I can select the desired payment method. After I accept the payment the `_listenToPurchaseUpdated(...)` method is called, as expected.
However, the call to `InAppPurchaseConnection.instance.completePurchase(p)` returns a `BillingResponse.developerError` and I get the following debug messages:

```
W/BillingHelper: Couldn't find purchase lists, trying to find single data.
I/flutter: result: BillingResponse.developerError (Purchase is in an invalid state.)
```

This error comes with the "test card, always approves" and also when I start a real transaction using PayPal. For the PayPal purchase I got a confirmation Email, that the transaction was successful.
In the documentation it says:

> Warning! Failure to call this method and get a successful response within 3 days of the purchase will result a refund on Android.

### Summarized question

How can I get the call to `InAppPurchaseConnection.instance.completePurchase(p)` to return a successful result?

### The purchase implementation

The code to setup in app purchases is implemented as shown in the documentation:

```dart
InAppPurchaseConnection.enablePendingPurchases();

Stream<List<PurchaseDetails>> purchaseUpdated = InAppPurchaseConnection.instance.purchaseUpdatedStream;

_subscription = purchaseUpdated.listen(_listenToPurchaseUpdated, onDone: () {
    _subscription.cancel();
}, onError: (error) {
  // handle error here.
});

...

Future<void> _listenToPurchaseUpdated(List<PurchaseDetails> purchaseDetailsList) async {
  for (var p in purchaseDetailsList) {
   
    // Code to validate the payment

    if (!p.pendingCompletePurchase) continue;

    var result = await InAppPurchaseConnection.instance.completePurchase(p);

    if (result.responseCode != BillingResponse.ok) {
      print("result: ${result.responseCode} (${result.debugMessage})");
    }
  }
}
```

To buy a consumable I have this method which queries the product details and calls `buyConsumable(...)`

```dart
Future<bool> _buyConsumableById(String id) async {
  final ProductDetailsResponse response = await InAppPurchaseConnection
      .instance
      .queryProductDetails([id].toSet());

  if (response.notFoundIDs.isNotEmpty || response.productDetails.isEmpty) {
    return false;
  }

  List<ProductDetails> productDetails = response.productDetails;

  final PurchaseParam purchaseParam = PurchaseParam(
    productDetails: productDetails[0],
  );

  return await InAppPurchaseConnection.instance.buyConsumable(
    purchaseParam: purchaseParam,
  );
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is to not call the `completePurchase(...)` method for consumable purchases. By default the library consumes the purchase for you which implicitly acts as a call to `completePurchase(...)`.

### Background

The call to `InAppPurchaseConnection.instance.buyConsumable(...)` has an optional boolean parameter `autoConsume` which is always `true`. This means that, on android, the purchase is consumed right before the callback to the `purchaseUpdatedStream`.
The documentation of the `completePurchase` method says the following:

> The [consumePurchase] acts as an implicit [completePurchase] on Android

### Code to fix the problem

```dart
Future<void> _listenToPurchaseUpdated(List<PurchaseDetails> purchaseDetailsList) async {
  for (var p in purchaseDetailsList) {

    // Code to validate the payment

    if (!p.pendingCompletePurchase) continue;
    if (_isConsumable(p.productID)) continue; // Determine if the item is consumable. If so do not consume it

    var result = await InAppPurchaseConnection.instance.completePurchase(p);

    if (result.responseCode != BillingResponse.ok) {
      print("result: ${result.responseCode} (${result.debugMessage})");
    }
  }
}
```